# Hyperledger Composer Identity issuing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I encounter the following problem when I try to issue a new identity :

*Treating unknown remoting type "issueidentityrequest" as "any"*

The identity is correctly issued (when I check with *composer-playground*) but the code ends in ERROR and I can't download the card. My code is the following :

```
`const identity = {
    "participant": 'org.acme.sample.Company#'+companyId,
    "userID": companyId,
    "options": {}
};`

`$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/system/identities/issue",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'blob',
    data: identity,`

    success: function (cardData) {
        console.log('CARD-DATA', cardData);
    },`
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log("Sorry, there was a problem!");
    },
    complete: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log("The request is complete!");
    }
});`
```

Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

might be best to see an end-to-end example https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc indeed the endpoint returns a business network card that gets imported. This is then used to create a card file on disk

eg

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/api/system/issue",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'blob',
  data: identity,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Paul but with `xhrFields` it doesn't work neither. On the other hand, it's fine with composer-playground. I would like to implement something similar on my back office.